# How to limit JQuery selectable-helper's range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a Table with JQuery's [selectable](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/) feature.My Table was selectable each **td** which are in the same column. Below is my full html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/css/schedulerGrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="/js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
        <script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
        <script src="/js/schedulerGrid.js" type="text/javascript">
        </head>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div class="scheduler-area">
            <div class="scheduler-container">
                <table class="scheduler">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="header">
                                <div class="header-name">01</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="header">
                                <div class="header-name">02</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="header">
                                <div class="header-name">03</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="header">
                                <div class="header-name">04</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="header">
                                <div class="header-name">05</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="header">
                                <div class="header-name">06</div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="header">
                                <div class="header-name">07</div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                            <td class="item"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And **JavaScript** for selectable

```
var currentCol;
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".scheduler-container").selectable({
                filter: ".item",
                start: function(event, ui) {
                    $(".item").removeClass("ui-selected");
                },
                stop: function(event, ui) {

                    //Reset selector. 
                    currentCol = undefined;
                },
                selecting: function(event, ui) {

                    if (currentCol === undefined) {
                        currentCol = $(ui.selecting).index();
                    }

                    var nthChild = parseInt(currentCol) + 1;
                    for (var i = 1; i <= $(".scheduler").children('tbody').children('tr').children('.item').length; i++) {

                        if (i != nthChild) {
                            $(".item.ui-selecting:nth-child(" + i + ")").each(function() {
                                $(this).removeClass("ui-selecting");
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    ;
                }
     });
});
```

And **CSS** is

```
.scheduler-area  {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding-top: 37px;
    background: #777777;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #777777 0%, #494949 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#777777), color-stop(100%,#494949));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777777 0%,#494949 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #777777 0%,#494949 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #777777 0%,#494949 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #777777 0%,#494949 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#777777', endColorstr='#494949',GradientType=0 );
}

.scheduler-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
.scheduler {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
.scheduler .item + .item {
  border-left:1px solid #777777;
}
.scheduler .item, .header {
  border-bottom:1px solid #777777;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  color: #000;
  padding: 25px;
}
.scheduler .header {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-left: 1px solid #777777;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.scheduler .header:FIRST-CHILD {
  border-left: none;
}
.scheduler .header .header-name{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -26px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #393C44;
  width: 165px;
}
.scheduler .header:first-child .header-name{
  border: none;
}

.scheduler .ui-selecting {
    background: #97B58F;
}

.scheduler .ui-selected {
    background: #4C6840;
    color: white;
}
.ui-selectable-helper {
    border:1px solid #747474; 
}
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE Link](http://jsfiddle.net/aaa7sun8/1/). 
My problem is I would like to restrict *selectable-helper*'s selection range but I have no idea how to do it. Table's elements are selectable in the same column.So, the selection should be bound within the same column. How can I figure it with CSS or JavaScript ?

Comment: If you don't clear enough with my question , [here](http://www.bryntum.com/examples/scheduler-latest/examples/weekview/weekview.html) is sample link that I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question right.

Do you want to achieve something like this?

So for this example it allows you to select only columns that are defined between columns range.

```
var columnsRange =[[0,1],[2,3],[0,3],[0,3],[1,3],[3,3],[1,3]];
var currentCol;
     $(".scheduler-container").selectable({
                filter: ".item",
                start: function(event, ui) {
                    $(".item").removeClass("ui-selected");
                },
                stop: function(event, ui) {

                    //Reset selector. 
                    currentCol = undefined;
                },
                selecting: function(event, ui) {

                    if (currentCol === undefined) {
                        currentCol = $(ui.selecting).index();
                    }                
                    var nthChild = parseInt(currentCol) + 1; //Add one as nthChild is not zero index
                    for (var i = 1; i <= $(".scheduler").children('tbody').children('tr').children('.item').length; i++) {

                        if (i != nthChild) {
                            $(".item.ui-selecting:nth-child(" + i + ")").each(function() {
                                $(this).removeClass("ui-selecting");
                            });
                        }
                    };
                    if (!isInRange($(ui.selecting))) {
                       $(ui.selecting).removeClass("ui-selecting");
                     }
                }
     });

function isInRange(cell){    
    if (cell.closest('tr').index() >=columnsRange[cell.index()][0] && cell.closest('tr').index() <=columnsRange[cell.index()][1])
    {        
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```